# can't save .zshrc file

Tags: terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh, iterm

I want to make aliases for my iterm2 so i tried to edit the .zshrc file.

But the problem is for some reason i can't save the file, it gives me

```
 unable to save .zshrc
```

I also tried to set alias straight from console and it works, but it can only be used in that current iterm session.

I use iterm2 and oh-my-zsh

Answer (score 1):

That's usually a *permissions* problem.  You are attempting to save a file which may be

- read-only
- owned by some other user
- stored in a directory to which you have no write-permission

There's not enough information in the question to be more specific.  But a usual pitfall lies in copying files (or directories) as **`root`** (which makes them owned by **`root`**) and attempting to edit them as a non-privileged user.

Comment: To answer some of your suggestion: I changed the file permission using chmod but has no effect, and my mac only has one user. I am new to mac (windows user before learning programming) so any tips as to how I can try to solve this problem?

Comment: @fritz Try `chown yourname:yourname .zshrc`. Use `whoami` to get your name.